# Changing a method for all instances of class at runtime

Tags: java, oop, reflection, runtime, overriding

Say I have two classes:

**AnimalPen.java**

```
public class AnimalPen {

    private ArrayList<Animal> animals;

    public AnimalPen() {
        animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        animals.add(new Dog("Freddy"));
        animals.add(new Dog("Doggy"));

        for (Animal a : animals) {
            animal.makeSound();
        }
    }

}
```

**Dog.java**

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}
```

Is there any possible way to use reflection to change what `makeSound()` in dog does, without modifying either of these classes? For example (this is just a suggestion. I don't have the best understanding of reflection) I make a class called `Dog` that extends `Animal`, and then at runtime exchange the `Dog.java` posted above with one that I created so that every single time `new Dog()` is called, it will create a new instance of my Dog instead of the one written above. I need this in a way so that I don't need to be knowing when new instances of Dog are being created, but they are using the class that I made with a modified `makeSound()` instead of the one that just prints out "Woof".

To give a better example, as an experiment I am trying to modify a Minecraft server without modifying the source code of the server itself. I am loading my code into the JVM via [CraftBukkit](http://bukkit.org) and I want to directly change how entities behave by modifying methods in the entity classes and then loading them into the server. I know this is possible to do through reflection, I was just more or less wondering if it is possible to "swap" an entire class at runtime with a modified version of it.

Comment: Sounds like you're interested in the Strategy pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Possible the factory pattern. Your explanation is very unclear, explain what situation you want to reach instead of trying to explain a halfassed solution.

Comment: There's things like AOP and Java Agents that might let you do this, but maybe it's possible to satisfy your real needs without reflection or these (complicated) concepts. Could you talk about the real scenario you're looking to satisfy, and maybe we can help identify a straight-forward approach?

Comment: @MarkElliot I updated with an example of what I am trying to accomplish. Now that I realize it, this whole time I was trying to ask a simple question by giving a complicated example

Comment: I don't think it will be feasible to do what you want via reflection. Changing method bodies isn't something reflection can do; it also can't adjust call-site addresses.

Comment: Can you create your own classes that serve as an adapter to the original minecraft classes? Direct the calls you don't want to intercept to the actual class and provide your own methods for those you want to intercept. I don't know how the MC setup works so I'm just providing options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot alter the method at run time with reflection. Reflection can be used to call methods, access fields, etc. There is no possible technique to alter a Java class at run time which would basically mean recompiling the source to byte code.

Comment: There are various debugger features that might be used, but they involve either recompiling the class on the fly or intercepting the calls and simulating a change to the class.

Answer (score 0):

As other guys have told, I don't think it is possible to solve your problem the way you need regarding Minecraft server and reflection.

I just did a few tests mostly for didactic purposes. Recently (from 2017) java comes with JShell which may get close to this but limited to the shell.

Let's take your example, the following code can be saved as a jsh file and opened on jshell:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.prefs.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Animal {
    String name;
    String sound = "grr";
    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println(sound);
    }

    public void setSound(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog(String name) {
        super(name);
    this.sound = "Woof";
    }

    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println(sound);
    }
}

public class AnimalPen {

    private ArrayList<Animal> animals;

    public AnimalPen() {
        animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        animals.add(new Dog("Freddy"));
        animals.add(new Dog("Doggy"));
        allMakeSound();
    }

    public void allMakeSound() {
        for (Animal a : animals) 
            a.makeSound();
    }

    public void setAnimalSound(int id, String newSound) {
        ((Animal)animals.get(id)).setSound(newSound);
    }
}

AnimalPen testAnimals = new AnimalPen();
```

Load it on jshell produces the following result:

```
jshell> /open /home/me/tmp/animals.jsh
Woof
Woof
```

jshell already creates an object for AnimalPen:

```
jshell> /vars
|    AnimalPen testAnimals = AnimalPen@51081592
```

Simply changing an object as expected we have:

```
jshell> testAnimals.setAnimalSound(1,"Meaw");

jshell> testAnimals.allMakeSound()
Woof
Meaw
```

But what is interesting is when we change the class. Changing the code for printing to "System.out.println(sound + " " + sound +" grr");":

```
jshell> /edit Dog 
|  modified class Dog
```

The result is:

```
jshell> testAnimals.allMakeSound()
Woof Woof grr
Meaw Meaw grr
```

As we can see, the objects inside of testAnimal object had their methods changed. It was applied for all instances. For some reason, I was not able to change testAnimal object itself. When I tried it, my instance was destroyed. But for those instances referenced by testAnimal object, it sounds to work.